# How can I use REST url as data in Vega-lite

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I have this REST API that returns tabular data in the following way:

```
{"data": [{"el1": 8, "el2": 9}, {"el1": 3, "el2": 4}]}
```

I would like to use el1 and el2 in a Vega-lite chart. How should I refer to the elements in the array?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [here](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/data.html#format):

> (`JSON` only) The JSON property containing the desired data. This parameter can be used when the loaded JSON file may have surrounding structure or meta-data. For example

```
"property": "values.features"
```

> is equivalent to retrieving `json.values.features` from the loaded JSON object.

It seems that you can try to specify the "property" property (punny, eh) on the format. Something like this:

```
"data": {
  "url": <your url here>,
  "format": {
    "type": "json",
    "property": "data"
  },
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I haven't actually tested this but it looks to be supported (: